# cypress clicking button no response

Tags: javascript, cypress

Hello I am new to cypress, I was trying out different functions on woolworths website.
When I tried to log in by pressing the login button, I get a waiting button like this but it's not progressing any further.

[[image: circling login button]]

And I am having the error in cypress console saying it is sending too many log in request:

[image: POST 429 too many requests]

The cypress and chrome console look like this:
[image]
[image: console error more]

Below is my cypress code to click it:

```js
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should('be.visible').click();
```

Would someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here, Thank you!

Comment: the 429 should be obvious your making too many requests and have been blocked, you shouldn't use cypress on a site you don't own

Comment: You could try changing your `user-agent` or mask your IP address.


- https://www.searchenginejournal.com/change-user-agent/368448/#close
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048880/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-change-user-agent-in-cypress-io
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531909/can-i-force-cypress-to-use-a-specific-ip-address

Comment: Can you add a `cy.wait(20000)` after click to debug and see what happens.

Comment: Was also getting an error at one of the http post request saying: AbortError: This XHR was aborted by your code -- check this stack trace below.at onReadyStateFn (https://www.woolworths.com.au/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:177056:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange (https://www.woolworths.com.au/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:176991:25)
@Alphan Das

Comment: Hey Patrick, your email and pwd are visible above.